# Only allow validated commits on master

Tags: git, gitlab

**Context**

We have a repo, hosted on a local gitlab instance.

It contains a ressource file, which should be valid. The validity is checked by a given script.

**What I want**

I want to ensure that, whenever the `master` branch is updated on the `gitlab` repo, the file at the new head of `master` passes the validation script.

**Possibilities explored**

- all updates to `master` should go through a Merge Request

  1. I haven't found a way to enable / disable the `Merge` button based on the result of a script,
  2. I could upload a script in the bare `hooks/` directory of the bare `git` repo managed by gitlab, but I don't know of a `pre-merge` hook in git
- updates to master can be pushed by developpers

  3. I know how to write and upload an `update` hook, which validates the master branch on the bare git repo,
     I don't know how to prevent other ways to update the `master` branch

**Question**

Using `gitlab` and `git`, how can I make sure that updates to the `master` branch only allow hops to validated versions of the file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Using Gitlab pipelines

What you're trying to setup is **Continous Integration**, (in Gitlab known as "Pipeline") to check whether a merge request will pass or fail your script. [Check out the Gitlab features page](https://about.gitlab.com/features/gitlab-ci-cd/)

The setup is quite straightforward:

1. You create a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, [which describes what script needs to be run in order to test your resource file](https://gitlab.com/help/ci/yaml/README). Please note that the script should exit with 0 if the test passes and with a non-zero value otherwise.
2. Dependent on whether your project is open source you choose if you want to use Gitlab's shared runners. A "runner" is a server application which runs your script every time it is toggled. You can setup a runner on your own server or use Gitlab's Runners.
3. Once setup correctly GitLab will always show if your resource file is valid or not.

[image: A configured pipeline] 
*Source: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines.html*

## Example

This short example might help you to setup your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file

```
stages:
    - tests

ResourceFileTests:
    stage: tests
    allow_failure: false
    script:
        - bash /path/to/the/validation_script.sh
```

You can use [GitLab's CI lint tool](https://gitlab.com/ci/lint) to check whether your configuration file is valid or not.